# Closing the FAB sub menu on user touch

Tags: android, floating-action-button, submenu

I am trying to implement an expandable fab, I implemented it and it works as expected i.e when the user taps on fab_main the submenu becomes visible and active, and when the user taps on the fab_main again the sub menu turn invisible and inactive.
What My problem is that I want the submenu to close (in case it is open) when the user taps on screen like for example the current activity

I have Tried using ontouch (which didn't work) and dispatchTouchEvent(which worked but I was not able to use the sub menu buttons

This is my code for how I implemented expandable FAB

```java
fab_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (isOpen) {
            textView_img_edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textview_bg_edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fab2_bg_edit.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab1_img_edit.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab_main.startAnimation(fab_anti_clock_wise);
            fab2_bg_edit.setClickable(false);
            fab1_img_edit.setClickable(false);
            isOpen = false;
        } else {
            textView_img_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textview_bg_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab2_bg_edit.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab1_img_edit.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab_main.startAnimation(fab_clock_wise);
            fab2_bg_edit.setClickable(true);
            fab1_img_edit.setClickable(true);
            isOpen = true;
        }
    }
});
```

I used this code in both onTouch and dispatchTouchEvent

```java
if (isOpen) {
    textView_img_edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textview_bg_edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fab2_bg_edit.startAnimation(fab_close);
    fab1_img_edit.startAnimation(fab_close);
    fab_main.startAnimation(fab_anti_clock_wise);
    fab2_bg_edit.setClickable(false);
    fab1_img_edit.setClickable(false);
    isOpen = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a `onTouchListener` on the base layout. You can check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and close your fab submenu (if it's open)  there.